# New ES6 class instance from an existing object

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to create a new ES6 class instance that would have access to properties of an existing object right within the constructor?

I have an ES5 class:

```
function ES5() {
    this.value = 123;
}
```

And I need to be able to create an ES6 class instance:

```
class ES6 {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.value); /* must print 123 */
    }
}
```

that would have access to the ES5 class properties from within the constructor.

Basically, I want something like:

```
Object.create(ES6.prototype, new ES5());
```

though I know this code doesn't work. But is there a way to make this type of logic work?

---

I have a library that accepts a function for creating new objects, and I have added a way to check if it is an ES6 class, to initialize it differently, with the `new` operand, while providing my own existing object for the class.

**NOTE:** This also means that class `ES6` has no knowledge of the `ES5` class existence, only of its properties. Or to put it otherwise, class `ES6` needs to get property `value` automatically, it cannot patch itself.

**more details**

My library executes `new ES5()` internally, while class `ES6` is declared on the client side. So they co-exist independently. And when the client passes me in the `ES6` class, I need to instantiate it in such a way that it thinks it extends class `ES5`, i.e. has access to the extra properties.

```
function createClass(func) {
  if(/* func is an ES6 class*/) {
      var a = new ES5();
      return /* new ES6 instance that has access to ES5 object properties */
  } else {
      return new ES5();
  }
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't know anything about `ES5`, how could it do `new ES5()`?

Comment: How is the relationship between `ES5` and `ES6` established?

Comment: My library executes `new ES5()` internally, while class `ES6` is declared on the client side. So they co-exist independently. And when the client passes me in the `ES6` class, I need to instantiate it in such a way that it thinks it extends class `ES5`.

Comment: But you have to tell `ES6` which class it's supposed to extend somehow.

Comment: Your example is incomplete, it just makes things worst and more vague than before.

Comment: Also define the words "class" and "properties"! Do you mean by "ES6 class" an instance of that class or the original class definition? Do you mean by properties the own properties of the instance (defined in the constructor) or evrything including prototype's methods?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir The answer that I accepted is exactly what I was looking for, if it helps understand the question also ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the prototype of the class to the ES5 instance. This will put the instance and the ES5 function in the prototype chain:

```js
function ES5() {
    this.value = 123;
}

class ES6 {
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.value); /* must print 123 */
    }
}
let e5 = new ES5()

Object.setPrototypeOf(ES6.prototype, e5)
let e6 = new ES6

// ES5 now in the prototype chain of e6
console.log("instance of ES5:", e6 instanceof ES5)
console.log("instance of ES6:", e6 instanceof ES6)

// they are linked by prototype (not sure if that's good or bad for your use):
console.log("es6 value: ", e6.value)
e5.value = "newValue"
console.log("es6 value: ", e6.value)
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! I would also include the older answer, like the one by ibrahim at the moment, for completeness, to cover every scenario ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t just one note though, this mutates the ES6 class itself. Any future instances of this class will be affected. Any future mutations will affect all the previous instances. Giving how `createClass` is defined I guess this will lead to other problems. I can't even tell if that's bad or not as I still don't understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes, it is a trade off, which means I would need to call `setPrototypeOf` before creating any new `ES6` instance, but it is still usable ;) b.t.w. I like your answer also, but I can't accept both of them :)

Comment: @vitaly-t Are you expecting only instances of the `ES5` class to be passed to `createClass`? If not this will lead to serious problems like instance that have properties they don't use (imagine you call `createClass` with an instance of another EcmaScript 5 class that doesn't have the `value` property after you passed the class `ES5` to it, the new `ES6` instance will still have the `value` property of the previous instance). Is that ok?

Comment: @vitaly-t ... I'm not arguing so that you'll accept my answer, I'm just trying to understand what you're looking for. Deleted mine anyway. :)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I can't say for sure, until I get to properly test all of this :) You should have kept your answer anyhow, it was good for very similar things ;) In fact, I may even end up using it, I just don't know yet :)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir is correct that this could be shaky. Once you create an ES6 instance, if you then change the prototype of the ES6 class, past instances will reflect this change.  So running `Object.setPrototypeOf(ES6.prototype, someotherinstance)` would effect everything because all the old instances would now be linked to the new prototype chain.